# How to change the position of JQuery Mobile List Filter (Input)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, filtering, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm using the jQUery Mobile List control along with its filter functionality. By default jQuery mobile prepends the search input above the `list ul`. I want to change the location of this input? I've been searching on the google but no luck on this. I have also gone through the jQuery docs also.

Comment: override this class `.ui-listview-filter` as in this example http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/RdFp9/ you can do it dynamically also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/V3CYc/

Because search form is not part of a listvew jQuery is needed for this change.

**HTML :**

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search fruits..." id="custom-listview">
    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cherry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cranberry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Grape</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS :**

```
.ui-listview-filter {
    margin: 15px -15px 15px !important;
}
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    var filter = $('#custom-listview').prev();
    $('#custom-listview').parent().append(filter);
});
```